# User product price will not changes after changing customer group on the same session

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have two customer groups like

**CG1** and **CG2** and for product **A**

CG1's price is 10 $

CG2's price is 20 $.

My **user** is currently on customer group 1 (**CG1**) and I switched him to customer group 2 (**CG2**). When I am switching him from group 1, his current session was on, but the product price didn't change to 20$ immediately. Only after re-login he was able to see the updated price.

Where is magento storing this session and how can we forcibly update even if the session is on ? Is there any kind of caching we need to clear.

How to resolve this?

Comment: You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,` class and update customer session

Comment: @KetanBorada inject means ? how